# Set variable of a running Python script

Tags: python, command-line

How can I access a running Python script's variable? Or access a function, to set the variable. I want to access it from the command line or from another Python script, that doesn't matter.

For example,
I have one script running run_motor.py, with a variable called mustRun. When the user pushes the stop button it should access the variable mustRun to change it to false.

Comment: Take a look at the [argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) library.

Comment: Please be more precise in what you want. This sounds like you are saying that the python command is already running and you want a different python script or command line call to access what it is doing. argparse allows you to access the arguments with which a python command was called from the command line (as input to main). Note that it also depends on your python version to determine if argparse had been added. version 2.6.6 does not have it yet and uses optparse

Comment: Sorry. I will edit my post.

Comment: From another python script ? From an external python script ? Where does the user pushes the button ? Is it in another process or in the same process ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to interact with a running python script and modify some variables in it (I don't know why you want to do that, but... meh) you can have a look at [Pyrasite](http://pyrasite.com/).

Here is a demo of Pyrasite on [asciinema](https://asciinema.org/a/1148)

This is damn impressive.

By the way just so you know, that's NOT the best practice for what you want to do. I assume this is for testing purpose because using that kind of script in production or something like that wouldn't be safe at all...

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This works. Thank you very much. I will accept it in 5 minutes.

Comment: Please don't use pyrasite in a production environment. You're not 'supposed' to do that. Just saying :)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way of accomplishing this is to run a small TCP server in a thread and have it change the variable you want to change when it receives a command to do so. Then write a python script that sends the stop command to that TCP server.

Comment: Not "easiest", but "cleanest", yes.